# Enabling a button when 2 select tag has been selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am doing a verification button. I have a button that is initially in disabled state. And i have three elements as the button enabler. 1 is input tag, 1 is select tag and another 1 is select tag. When those 3 is filled and selected, the button should be enabled and back to disabled again when one or all of the elements is back to blank.

This is what ive done so far and it doesnt work. Please help me

```
$(window).load(function(){

    $("#devicemask").on('keyup blur', function(){
        $('#set-sr-property').prop('enabled', this.value.trim().length);
    });

            $('#flightselect').change(function() {
                var op =$(this).val();
                if(op ! = '') {                 
                    $('#set-sr-property').prop('disabled',false);
                } else {
                      $('#set-sr-property').prop('disabled', true);
                }   
            });

            $('#crewselect').change(function() {
                var op =$(this).val();
                if(op ! = '') {                 
                    $('#set-sr-property').prop('disabled',false);
                } else {
                      $('#set-sr-property').prop('disabled', true);
                }   
            });
        });
```

Comment: please elaborate..

Comment: Oh, you need to check each value of element inside each event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check each value between each event. Basically will be look like this.

```
var input = $('#devicemask');
var select1 = $('#flightselect');
var select2 = $('#crewselect');
var button = $('#set-sr-property');

input.on('keyup blur', function(){
    if (input.val().trim().length >= 1 &&
          select1.val() !== '' && 
          select2.val() !== '') {
          button.prop('disabled', false);
    }else{
            button.prop('disabled', true);
    }  
});

select1.change(function() {
    if (input.val().trim().length >= 1 &&
          select1.val() !== '' && 
          select2.val() !== '') {
          button.prop('disabled', false);
    }else{
            button.prop('disabled', true);
    }    
});

select2.change(function() {
    if (input.val().trim().length >= 1 &&
          select1.val() !== '' && 
          select2.val() !== '') {
          button.prop('disabled', false);
    }else{
            button.prop('disabled', true);
    }   
});
```

You sure can simplifize it. Sample fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/phv5yty8

---

Anyways, I tried to wrap it inside `$.load()` but doesn't work. I don't know why. So `$.ready()` may fit on this.